# Position content after absolute positioned divs

Tags: html, css

I have a `relative` positioned div which contains another three `absolute` positioned divs which I use as a slider. Each of the three `absolute` positioned divs contains an image with `width:100%`.

The problem is that when I want to position content **under** my slider, **the content overlaps with the slide**r (because the divs are absolute postioned and I don't know the actual height - it varies because the image width is 100%).

How can I position content under the slider?

Currently I am using a javascript function that retrieves the image's height and adds that height as a padding to the content underneath, but I'd prefer to use pure css.

Is it possible? (I would prefer **NOT** to use media queries for this, because there would be a looot of resolutions to take care of).

Here goes the code: (for a live example check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6ppqxLf/5/)

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="latime_100">

        <img src="poze/sageata_st.png" class="navigare" id="navigare_st" onclick="go_prev();"></img>

        <div id="slider_1" class="slider" >

            <img src="http://www.freestockphotos.name/wallpaper-original/wallpapers/download-images-of-gentle-dogs-6866.jpg"></img>



        </div>

        <div id="slider_2" class="slider">

            <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-rZmCIp0C-hQ/Tx6aCFeweoI/AAAAAAAAAnQ/WqIEVBTIzRk/s1600/Cool-Tiger-Wallpaper-1920x1080-HD.jpg"></img>



        </div>

        <div id="slider_3" class="slider">

            <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwazmPOPcUTK1AmVSPQjH7YLlBywxTpkQi4LEQ40HJOg6_8Qyw"></img>



        </div>

        <img src="poze/sageata_dr.png" class="navigare" id="navigare_dr" onclick="go_next();"></img>
    </div>
```

CSS **(navigare_st and navigare_dr are the slider arrows)**:

```
.slider{

    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

.slider img{

  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;

  min-width: 1024px;

}

#slideshow{


    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:100;
}

#navigare_st{

    position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    left:0px;
    top:45%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:2.5%;
}

#navigare_dr {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 45%;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:2.5%;
}
```

Comment: if you want to make a slider its better you set a fixed height rather than the 100%, the image slider doesn't look good as the height of image changes. my advice wrap the images inside a div (with fixed width & height) then set the image atrib to 100%

Comment: Probably you know already, but if You make a slider with images different height AND you want content behind to follow the flow as if not using position:absolute... The user experience of your web is not going to be very good (to say at least)... all content moving up and down all time.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez The images have the same height, those in the fiddle are just for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand what the problem is.
But here is my attempt at adding extra content to the bottom of the pictures, without overlap.

(ignore the javascript its just for demo)

```js
var curslide = 0;
var elements;

$(document).ready(function() {
  elements = $('.slider');
  elements.hide();
  elements.first().show();

  $('#navigare_st').click(function() {
    if (curslide > 0) {
      curslide--;
      elements.hide();
      elements.eq(curslide).show();
    }
  });
  $('#navigare_dr').click(function() {
    if (curslide < elements.length) {
      curslide++;
      elements.hide();
      elements.eq(curslide).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  //position: absolute;
}
.slider img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
}
#slideshow {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 100;
}
#navigare_st {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 1000;
  left: 0px;
  top: 45%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#navigare_dr {
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  right: 0px;
  top: 45%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
.extra {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow" class="latime_100">

  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_back_arrow-128.png" class="navigare" id="navigare_st" />

  <div id="slider_1" class="slider">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />



  </div>

  <div id="slider_2" class="slider">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" />



  </div>

  <div id="slider_3" class="slider">

    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food" />

  </div>

  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu/22/circle_back_arrow-128.png" class="navigare" id="navigare_dr" />

  <div class="extra">
    Here comes the extra content?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Making an element on a page have a dynamic height is not a good practice.
Either try to get your images the same height, or give the slideshow container the height of the 'heightest' image.

Typically, slideshows with fade effect use the `float: left;` for the slides, then a `clear:both` after the last slide.

But if you insist on keeping that configuration and just want a quick fix, this code will do the trick :

```
$('#slideshow').css('height', $('#slider_'+i+' img').height());
```

Copy it inside your slider_init and go_slide functions.

Cordially

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to stick with pure css solution, just give your first slider element to `position:relative`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `position: absolute` for this task.  Why?  Because using `position: absolute` removes elements from the document flow, so browsers will think they take up no space on the page.
Instead, use `float:left` or `float:right`.  It will accomplish the same task, but will cause the parent div to grow to fit the content.

Like so:

```
.slider {
    width:100%;
    float: left;
}
```

I have an updated version of your jfiddle that shows it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/udfjm089/3/

To be frank with you though, unless it is essentially necessary to your layout, I wouldn't recommend this.  Setting a fixed height for a wrapper div with `overflow: hidden` would look much nicer, and not cause your page content to bounce around.